# Migrate software to a new machine in Ubuntu

Tags: installation, stata, ubuntu-16.04

I need to install an old version of licensed statistical software (Stata version 8) in Ubuntu 16.04 to teach a class. My machine no has no cd drive, the medium where the Stata distribution I purchased years ago resides.

I do, however, have the software in question already installed in my old office computer (running Ubuntu 14.04). Could I simply copy the `/usr/local/stata8/` directory to my new machine, and assume it will work?

Any advice will be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a CD of the software, definitely I would suggest that you use it. Just find some laptop or desktop with a USB port and cd drive and copy it to the USB stick. 
There are a few other options, like if no USB stick is available, then connect the new Ubuntu via network to a computer with a CD drive and transfer the software over the network. 
I think the least reliable option would be to copy directly the installed software  directory from one computer to another.
Please try some computer repair shop if they charge decently or some store if they can provide an external USB CD ROM just to run the installation. Since we are talking about licensed software and I am not any professional at that, I can't make any suggestions to copy directly directories over the network of some already installed products. I am a Linux fan. If you have a bootable Linux stick, then buy a cheap CDROM from ebay that works with the hardware. Understandably you take the final decisions.

Comment: problem is finding a machine with a cd drive... will keep trying to locate it, unless another solution shows its head.

Answer (score 2):

Any Stata installation directory can be simply copied and pasted to another directory/machine. You also need to manually copy your `ado` files (downloaded from SSC or self-made) from the old computer to the new computer. To know the directories, execute `sysdir` in Stata command window. Paste your `ado` folder to a similar directory on the new machine.

These steps work on Windows and Linux/Mac. And before copying the directory it is better to zip the entire `stata8` folder - that will significantly reduce copying time since there are plenty of small-sized files.

Answer (score 1):

You can give it certainly a try, if there are no other options, like copying the installer CD image.

If the machine is not the same architecture (i686 or x86-64) it will not work, find out with `uname -m` on a terminal.

In case the software includes all library dependecies in `/usr/local/stata8` it should work directly.

If it uses system installed libraries it may not work. Here you would have to find out which libraries to install via `apt`. It is also possible that older versions of packaged libraries are needed.